# Why does an electric motor, of 800 kW at 400 V, have 7 connectors for power cables?

Tags: motors, electrical, power-transmission

I found a Vybo electric motor and noticed that it has seven connectors for power cables.
I also found a [Variable Speed Drive, Altivar Process ATV900, System ATV960, 800/630 kW, 400 V](https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/ATV960C80Q4X1/variable-speed-drive-altivar-process-atv900-high-performance-system-atv960-800-630-kw-400-v-ip23/) and [its datasheet](https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/download-pdf/ATV960C80Q4X1) lists many characteristics out of which I mention:

- Motor power: 800 kW,
- Continuous output current: 1420 A at 2.5 kHz,
- Line current: 1335 A at 400 V,
- Motor recommended cable cross section: 6 x (3 x 185 mm²) or 5 x (3 x 240 mm²).

**Question**: Should I understand that the Vybo motor in question needs 6 three phase cables, each of them with 3 conductors of 185 mm² in cross section, or 5 cables with three conductors of 240 mm², each; independently of the fact that the motor is powered from the VSD or directedly from the 400 V, 50 Hz industrial source?

[image]
Fig. 1. [ELECTRIC MOTOR 800KW H17RL-450-4, 1488RPM, 380V-400V-420V, Low Voltage](https://vyboelectric.com/electric-motors/800kw-electric-motor-800kw-h17rl-450-4-1488rpm-380v-400v-420v-440v-460v-660v-690v-720v-50hz-60hz-ic411-ie3-sales-best-price-lv-motors-immediately-new-buy/).

Comment: Do you think those 7 things are connectors? Or could they be cable glands with the actual connectors inside? And 7 to allow for control and sensing cables as well as power cables?

Comment: It does sound like each of the 3 internal coils are controlled fully separately with a high current connector, plus a protective earth.

Comment: @SolarMike , They are cable glands. However, according to this guide (see: https://www.sghcable.com/pdf/cable_usage/App-2E%20V2.pdf) a 3-ph AC cable can carry min 245 A/ phase. So, six 3-ph AC cables in parallel (with all 6 phases a ( and b, c) connected together at ends) carry 245 A x 6 = 1470 A/phase. Now, if we go back to the 800 kW motor and calculate its line currents in ideal conditions, we get: I = 800kW/(400V*sqrt(3))= 1154 Amp, so the 6 AC cables mentioned above are well suited to power this motor. This is an explanation found by my for the 7 glands of the motor but I might be wrong.